# Definition of algebraic K-theory space

Tags: category-theory, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Let $(C,wC)$ be a Waldhausen category. The algebraic K-theory space is the loop space of the classifying space of the simplicial pointed category $wS_*C$, i.e. of the topological realization of the bisimplicial set $N_*wS_*C$.

Is there a specific reason we want to consider $wS_*C$ instead of $S_*C$?

Moreover, why we want to consider the loop space instead of classifying space of the simplicial pointed category $wS_*C$ directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ignore w and consider just $S_* C$, that's equivalent to considering $w S_* C$, where $w$ is defined to consist of all the isomorphisms.  The notation for that family $w$ is usually $i$.

Comment: Can you explain the equivalence?

Comment: It's part 2 of the corollary after lemma 1.4.1 of Waldhausen's paper "Algebraic K-theory of Spaces".

Comment: Intuitively, the reason for the equivalence is that filtrations can "swallow" isomorphisms.  I.e., if A_0 -> ... -> A_n is a chain of composable monomorphisms, and for some i, A_i -> A'_i is an isomorphism, then you can insert A'_i into the chain to get a chain whose length is 1 more.  Such chains of length 1 more play a role in simplicial homotopies.

Comment: For further intuition, see lemma 1.6.5, the swallowing lemma.

Comment: PS: Another answer has been deleted, but it contained something worthwhile: if you don't use w, then you aren't studying what you want to study.

Comment: PS: Get the papers of Waldhausen here: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~fw/

Comment: PS: Taking the loop space is done simply so $\pi_0$ of the thing is $K_0$.  Otherwise it would be $\pi_1$, which is sort of annoying.

Comment: Another way to explain swallowing is this.  Suppose $A \to B$ is an isomorphism of objects of $S_n C$.  That gives a $(1,n)$-simplex of the bisimplicial set $i S_* C$, but it also gives a simplicial map $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^n \to S_* C$, which on each nondegenerate $n+1$-simplex is what I said before.